Can a son maintain his father's account?
Can a son maintain his father's account?
For example, can the account undergo change and the son start using it, such as changing the profile picture, name, description, etc. Are there any legal limitations?

Legal limitations are only the Terms of service. And even there I'm not sure if failure to comply with the terms has more implications beyond getting the account terminated. The cited code of conduct is even less but can still lose you your account. And I'm not a lawyer. But why not having two accounts, one for father and one for the son, each with their own profile picture, ...? Sure, getting rep these days might be harder, but asking and answering is always possible. And it would make comparison between accounts easier if every account belongs to only a single person.

Sharing accounts is against the rules under the Inauthentic usage policy:

Furthermore, we do not allow what we define as inauthentic usage of our systems, such as:
[...]

Sharing accounts/profiles between different individuals, even if these individuals work for or represent the same corporation or organization. Each account/profile may represent and be used by only one individual person throughout the lifetime of the profile/account. Stack Exchange may expressly grant written permission that an account/profile is not subject to this restriction.


The last line indicates that you may seek an exception to this rule, but there's no guarantee that it'll be granted. As a word of warning, I've seen accounts that were taken over (that obviously didn't ask permission before the transfer) be banned permanently from Stack Exchange.

The question doesn't really talk about sharing, rather maintaining and starting to use after change. This might include some sort of inheritance of accounts instead of sharing at the same time. On the other hand, it doesn't seem to make a difference for the quote.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution the question is about "maintaining", which is neither sharing nor inheriting. I see it as a state where both people would use it, but the "son" would only "maintain" it, not actually use it to post.
